# code successful but cant see the output in ORACLE PLSQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, output

A simple loop in PLQSL developer. successful execution but cant see any output in OutPut tab.

checked the output tab for the output which is a series of 'EVEN' and 'ODD' till 99 iteration
the code was successful.

below is the simple code

```
DECLARE 
n NUMBER :=1;

BEGIN
    FOR n IN 1..100
    LOOP 
        IF MOD(n,2)=0 THEN 
          dbms_output.put_line('even');
        ELSE 
          dbms_output.put_line('odd');
        END IF;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

the code was successful.

Comment: Did you enable DBMS output in PLSQL Developer?

Comment: im sorry but im new to this tool. last time i would get the output when i had used..a simple "DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE()" is an invalid statement in here..

Comment: You do not need to use `DECLARE` as `n` is defined by the `FOR` loop and shadows the `n` in the outer block. You can also get rid of the `IF` statement and use a `CASE` expression. [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/j2dHGmM1)